# How to create TABLESPACE in postgreSQL 9.5.7?

Tags: postgresql

I'm try to create the tablespace in postgres 9.5.7. I'm using this query:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE fastspace OWNER postgres LOCATION '/home/indianic/Dexter/';
```

And It show this error

```
 ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/home/indianic/Dexter": Operation not permitted

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not set permissions on directory "/home/indianic/Dexter": Operation not permitted
SQL state: 42501
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You must change the owner of the directory so that it belongs to the Linux user *postgres* and also group *postgres* and then do a chmod 770 on the directory.